# Como acessar variável de outra controller - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Como faço pra acessar variáveis de outra `controller`?

Por exemplo:

Tenho uma `controller X`, e na action `index`, crio uma variável (ou uma constante).
Da `controller Y`, quero acessar o valor da variável (ou constante) da `controller X`.

É possível fazer isso?
Lembrando que cada action de cada `controller`, em minha aplicação, terá uma variável que deverá ser acessível de outra `controller`.

Controller ExemploX

```
class ExemploXController 
    {
        $dependencias = array("index","listar");

        public function index()
            {
                echo "Index";
            }
        public function funcaoX()
            {
                echo "Funcão X";
            }
        public function listar()
            {
                echo "listando";
            }
    }
```

Controller ExemploY

```
class ExemploYController
    {
        $dependencias = array("index","atualizar");

        public function index()
            {
                //pegar o valor da variável $dependencias da controller ExemploXController
                $dependency[] = ExemploXController->dependencias;
            }
        public function funcaoY()
            {
                echo "Funcão Y";
            }
        public function atualizar()
            {
                echo "atualizar";
            }
    }
```

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo simples, mas concreto? O que você está pedindo provavelmente dá pra fazer de outra maneira.

Comment: Ok. Adicionei. Como eu faria isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acessar variáveis de outros controladores é completamente diferente de acessar métodos ou ações deles.

Os `controllers` do CakePHP são apenas classes comuns, então, em tese, você poderia acessar seus atributos e métodos da mesma forma como faria com qualquer classe, bastando para isso carregar o respectivo arquivo.

Uma forma de fazer isso é usando o [`App::import`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html). Veja o exemplo da própria documentação:

```php
// The same as require('Controller/UsersController.php');
App::import('Controller', 'Users');

// We need to load the class
$Users = new UsersController();
```

Como a própria documentação indica, isso é equivalente a usar diretamente o método `require`. Alternativamente, você poderia criar um arquivo com as constantes que você precisa e incluir esses arquivos no seu código, usando onde for necessário.

Comment: Foi exatamente o que fiz agora, antes de vir aqui. Pensamos juntos.De qualquer forma, obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Olá, você pode criar um `requestAction`.
Com ele você pode usar tanto no mesmo controller quanto em outros controllers, mas não se esqueça de criar o *elemment* de *cache*.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/pt/controllers.html#Controller::requestAction

Comment: Essa foi a melhor resposta. =)

Comment: @IgorMartins Esta é uma boa resposta se você quiser chamar um método de outro controlador. Mas fazer um request para recuperar uma constante?

Comment: @utluiz `requestAction` não serve apenas para chamar um método de um controler. segundo a documentação `Este método chama uma ação de um controller de qualquer lugar e retorna os dados da ação requisitada.`. `Você pode usar o requestAction() para recuperar uma view totalmente renderizada passando 'return' no array de opções: requestAction($url, array('return'));`. Sem contar que ele vai requisitar menos memória por faezr o uso do cache.

Comment: Foi exatamente isso o que eu disse. Mas isso simplesmente não responde à pergunta.

Comment: A partir do momento que ele pode setar uma variável em um `action` de um `controller` e não precisar importar um `controller` inteiro para conseguir resgatar o `action` que ele precisa, responde sim.